# FFMPEG: Dynamic change of bit_rate for Video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, bitrate

I use ffmpeg codes in my C++ app and would like to control the bit_rate parameter for VIDEO there. I tried to change its value in work (via ost->st->codec->codec->bit_rate), but ffmpeg did not wish to change it. 
Perhaps anybody knows how to make it?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried like this and its working for me.

```
     avcodec_init();

     avcodec_register_all();

     codec = avcodec_find_encoder(CODEC_ID_H263);

     c = avcodec_alloc_context();

     picture= avcodec_alloc_frame();

        c->bit_rate = bitrate;
        c->width = w;
        c->height = h;
        c->time_base= (AVRational){1,framerate};
        c->pix_fmt = PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

avcodec_close(c);

av_free(c);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it will not work for me. Because that operation is used only at start program (for init). So if  I will change a value in  c->bit_rate during work, the codec will ignore it.

Comment: once you init codec with specific bitrate you have to re-init the codec for changing bitrate dynamically.

Comment: How can I do it, ffmpeg has some function for re-init or I should call transcode_init() again?

Comment: first you need to close the codec already inited **avcodec_close(c);** & **av_free(c);** and than you can re-init the same codec with diffrent bit_rate.

Comment: > upvote  - sorry I cannot find where I can do it at a page :(

Comment: sorry, I cannot do it - Vote Up requires 15 reputation

Comment: Does it work? I am using ffmpeg in C+++ to encode a video file. It works well, except bit_rate does not work, no matter what value I set.